# Precision of orbital period of exoplanets vs solar system planets (Extrasolar Planets Encyclopedia)

Tags: planet, solar-system, exoplanet, orbital-elements

I noticed that the [Extrasolar Planets Encyclopedia](http://exoplanet.eu/) lists the orbital period of L 98-59 b in days to 7 decimal places. Can astronomers really measure orbital period of exoplanets to greater precision than planets of the solar system?

Here's a screen shot including some other entries, the number of digits varies by object:

[image: screen shot of the Extrasolar Planets Encyclopedia]